# Unable to run WAMP Server

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I tried installing WAMP Server in Win 7 64 bit version. I got "MSVCR100.DLL" missing I downloaded and installed. Again unable to run then I downloaded and installed "VCREDIST_x64.exe from stachoverflow site. Still m unable to run WAMP Server. Please help me out in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall wamp and then install VCREDIST_x64.exe first and then install the wamp 64 bit... If it's doesn't work you can try installing wamp server 32 bit even on a 64 bit as an alternative you can go for XAMMP server.